Does there exist a pairing function in the $\mathbb R^2$ domain?
For short: Does a two binary function exist, $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, meeting $\forall\left(x_1, y_1\right), \left(x_2,y_2\right),f\left(x_1, y_1\right)\neq f\left(x_2,y_2\right)\Rightarrow x_1\neq x_1,y_1\neq y_2$?
In addition, I want $f$ to be constructed by elementary function.

Since you call it a “pairing function”, I assume that the condition you want is actually
$$\forall(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb R^2\:\bigl(f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\implies(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)\bigr),$$
or equivalently,
$$\forall(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb R^2\:\bigl((x_1,y_1)\ne (x_2,y_2)\implies f(x_1,y_1)\ne f(x_2,y_2)\bigr).$$
That is, $f$ is an injection of $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$.
Such a pairing function certainly exists. In fact, pairing functions, even bijective, exist on all infinite sets (using the axiom of choice), but for $\mathbb R$, it is easy to define a pairing function explicitly: e.g., if the decimal expansion of $x$ and $y$ is
$$\begin{align*}
x&=u_nu_{n-1}\dots u_0{.}x_1x_2x_3\dots,\\
y&=v_nv_{n-1}\dots v_0{.}y_1y_2y_3\dots,
\end{align*}$$
(possibly padded with leading $0$s to the same $n$), let
$$f(x,y)=u_nv_n\dots u_1v_1u_0v_0{.}x_1y_1x_2y_2x_3y_3\dots\,.$$
(Strictly speaking, this actually gives a pairing function $\mathbb R_{\ge0}^2\to\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, but you can do something intelligent with the signs to make it work for $\mathbb R$.)
“Elementary function” does not have a generally agreed-upon definition. However, it seems reasonable to assume that whatever definition of elementary function you use, all such functions will be piecewise continuous.
Then no elementary pairing function $f$ exists: if it did, we could restrict it to one continuous piece with nonempty interior, thus we would obtain a continuous injective function $g=f\restriction([a,b]\times[c,d])\colon[a,b]\times[c,d] \to\mathbb R$ for some $a<b$, $c<d$. Let $S=g([a,b]\times[c,d])$ be the image of $g$, and pick $w\in\mathbb R$ such that $S\cap(-\infty,w)\ne\varnothing\ne S\cap(w,+\infty)$, which is possible as $|S|\ge2$. Then $g^{-1}((-\infty,w))$ and $g^{-1}((w,+\infty))$ form a partition of $([a,b]\times[c,d])\smallsetminus g^{-1}(w)$ into two nonempty disjoint relatively open subsets, but this contradicts the fact that $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ remains connected when you remove one point.
Alternatively, since $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is compact and $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff, $g$ must be a homeomorphic embedding, but this is impossible as $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ has dimension $2$, whereas $\mathbb R$ has dimension $1$.

Sorry for my mistake, I wrote a wrong formula in my question, what I really want is that $\forall\left(x_1, y_1\right), \left(x_2,y_2\right),f\left(x_1, y_1\right)\neq f\left(x_2,y_2\right)\Rightarrow x_1\neq x_1,y_1\neq y_2\in\mathbb{R}$. I hope you can tolerate my mistakes. My major is not mathematics, but I am really curious about this question, thank you for your answer!

P.S:The "pairing function" referred to Cantor pairing function.

I really doubt the formula you wrote now is what you want. It is equivalent to $f$ being constant: on the one hand, a constant function does satisfy the formula; on the other hand, the formula is equivalent to the contrapositive $x_1=x_2\text{ or }y_1=y_2\implies f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$, which implies for any $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$: $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$.

Sorry, but I mean $f(x_1,y_1)\neq f(x_2, y_2)$

You mean $f(x_1,y_1)\ne f(x_2,y_2)$ where? It's already part of the formula you wrote, so you mean something else? Give a complete coherent description of what you want. Preferably using words rather than formulas, since I strongly suspect that you do not understand the meaning of the symbols.

Oh, sorry, please forgive my foolish mistake once again. I misunderstood the meaning of your response. What I want is a binary function whose domain is within $\mathbb{R}^2$ , and for any two ordered pairs, their values are always different.

My professional level is indeed lacking. I am very sorry if my stupidity has caused you any discomfort. If my explanation is unclear, then I will try to learn more.....

"For any two different ordered pairs, their values are different" is exactly the formula in my answer, as I assumed this was the intended meaning from the beginning.

I added the (equivalent) contrapositive formula to the answer, if it helps readability.

So I said I misunderstood the meaning of your response, thank for your patience...
